# Check if value appears in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list. I want to see if it appears in one of the other sheets and return a string dependent on the sheet it is in.

E.g pseudocode:

```
value = "Hi"
If value in sheet 2 Then
  return "Yes"
If value in sheet 3 Then
  return "TDB"
Else
  return " "
```

The code I have so far

```vb
Public Function Check(product As String) As String

    Dim BLRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim BL As Worksheet
    Dim TBDRange As Range
    Dim TBD As Worksheet
    Dim result As String

    Set BL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set BLRange = BL.Range("A1:A1000")
    Set TBD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set TBDRange = TBD.Range("A1:A1000")

    For Each xlCell In BLRange
        If xlCell.Value = product Then
            Check = "Yes"
        End If
    Next xlCell

    For Each xlCell In TBDRange
        If xlCell.Value = product Then
            Check = "TBD"
        End If
    Next xlCell

    Check = ""
End Function
```

When I call `Check("Hi")` I get `#VALUE!`

Comment: Does this need to be a UDF? Looks like it could be a simple pair of `VLOOKUP`s.

Comment: Hi, yeah I would prefer a `VLOOKUP` but the return has to be in the same column, and I didn't think you could get it to return the "Y" or "TBD" depending on the sheet it came from. All the data in Sheets 2 and 3 are in column A

Comment: Even if your value IS found, you're always going to return "" because of the last line in your function.

Comment: Ooooh, I thought the `Check = "Y"` would kill the function @dwirony how do you think I could end it on the correct value? cheers

Comment: @GingerDom on the next line after that you can include `Exit Function`

Comment: I would just use the `Range.Find` method here

Comment: @GingerDom Putting `Exit Function` like Kubie suggested after each of the `Check = "Yes"` and `Check = "TBD"` would do the trick. But I would think your `#VALUE` error is because you're not wrapping your string in quotation marks in your formula.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of the function using `find` like @urdearboy mentioned...

```
Public Function Check(product As String) As String

    Dim BLRange As Range
    Dim TBDRange As Range
    Dim fndRng As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set BLRange = .Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
        Set TBDRange = .Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("A")
    End With

    Set fndRng = BLRange.Find(product)
    If Not fndRng is Nothing Then Check = "Yes": Exit Function

    Set fndRng = TBDRange.Find(product)
    If Not fndRng is Nothing Then Check = "TBD": Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: @Egalth - if the Find method doesn't find the search term, the range variable will return Nothing, not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (already tested and works)

```
Public Function Check(product As String) As String

Dim BLRange As Range
Dim BL As Worksheet
Dim TBDRange As Range
Dim TBD As Worksheet
Dim result As String

Set BL = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set BLRange = BL.Range("A1:A1000")
Set TBD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set TBDRange = TBD.Range("A1:A1000")

Check = "none"

For Each xlCell In BLRange
 If xlCell.Text = product Then
    Check = "Yes"
    GoTo a
 End If
Next xlCell

For Each xlCell In TBDRange
 If xlCell.Text = product Then
    Check = "TBD"
    GoTo a
 End If
Next xlCell

Exit Function

a:


End Function
```